# Python change list item

Tags: python, list, function, syntax, call-by-value

I am wondering why when changing values to a list by calling a function, there is such a difference in the following two scenarios (assign new value to **list** v.s. to **list[:]**). I guess it has something to do with call-by-value/call-by-reference.

Code

```
def rotate1(nums, k) -> None:   
  nums = nums[-k:]+nums[:-k]
  print(f"In rotate1: {nums}")
  
def rotate2(nums, k) -> None:   
  nums[:] = nums[-k:]+nums[:-k]
  print(f"In rotate2: {nums}")  

ls1 = [1,2,3,4]
rotate1(ls1, 2)
print(f"Outside rotate1: {ls1}\n")

ls2 = [1,2,3,4]
rotate2(ls2, 2)
print(f"Outside rotate2: {ls2}\n")
```

Output

```
In rotate1: [3, 4, 1, 2]
Outside rotate1: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In rotate2: [3, 4, 1, 2]
Outside rotate2: [3, 4, 1, 2]
```

ls1 value does not change after calling rotate1;
whereas ls2 value changes after calling rotate2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same problem is explained exactly in this page [Is Python pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)

> As we know, in Python, “Object references are passed by value”.

In both rotate methods, the `nums` creates a new variable to point to object [1,2,3,4]. The difference is:

- `nums = nums[-k:]+nums[:-k]` causes `nums` to point to a new object.
- `nums[:] = nums[-k:]+nums[:-k]` causes the object pointed by `nums` changed.

So, outside the methods, only the `rotate2` really changes the object of `ls2`.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `rotate1` you are assigning a new variable `nums` which replaces the variable `nums` that came in the argument. This will not affect the list outside the function because you are replacing the variable that points to where the values are allocated in memory, you are not changing the values in memory. Essentially, your new list `[3, 4, 1, 2]` is being stored in a new address in memory. Now you have your original list `ls1` and the new list `nums` allocated in different addresses in memory.

In your function `rotate2` you are changing the values that are stored in memory, instead of changing the pointer. When you use `nums[:]` the variable `nums` remains untouched, what changes are the values in memory that the variable `nums` points to. That's why your list outside gets updated too.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, talking about memory and pointers is only going to be confusing to most users of Python.

Comment: I think you are right, but it's good to have some diversity of answers so they can build a more holistic understanding of the problem. Thanks for the feedback though.